# .load(url) on page load

Tags: jquery

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#foo2").load("carousel/todos.html");
        $('#foo2').animate({ "opacity":"1" });
        $('#carouselselectitem1').css({ 'color' : '#FF0000', 'opacity' : '1' })
    });
</script>
```

`animate()` and `css()` work perfectly, but `load()` doesn't import my HTML. If I use a `click` handler with a button it works fine.

Anybody know why?

Comment: make sure u have a correct path there....

Comment: yes, it's the correct path. With click event works fine. But i want similar to OnLoad on javascript. Is this possible?

Comment: What you want isn't clear but you probably should execute the animate only after the load has completed.

Comment: thanks dystroy, but never load. i'm desesperate xD

Comment: what does the javascript console say the error is? If in chrome you press F12, then select console and reload the page, does it give any errors?

Comment: `foo2` is a `iframe`, right?

Comment: Are you getting this error: `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` ?

Comment: Which browser are you trying this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To protect you, a browser will not load a page in automatically (giving the `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error).
You can relaunch your browser to allow this sort of activity *or* put it on a webserver and it should work.

[HTTP Access Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: This doesn't explain *" If I use a click handler with a button it works fine."*.

Comment: Different browsers implement the Same Origin Policy differently. Some will allow it if the user has initiated the `load()`

Comment: Only don't work in Chrome and Opera and the console results said XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/thaymus/Desktop/NUEVO%20VEKTORLAB/html/carousel/todos.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. How i can fix this? thanks

edited: OK, online WORK. Not in Local

Comment: You can either upload it to a web server (either local or live) or you can open chrome allowing Same Origin using ` --allow-file-access-from-files` after `chrome.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Try either this, it could be that foo aint ready to load, or some cache problems

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
    $("#foo2").load("carousel/todos.html");
    $('#foo2').animate({ "opacity":"1" });
    $('#carouselselectitem1').css({ 'color' : '#FF0000', 'opacity' : '1' })
 },1000);


});
```

or try this

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#foo2").load("carousel/todos.html?"+ Math.random());
        $('#foo2').animate({ "opacity":"1" });
        $('#carouselselectitem1').css({ 'color' : '#FF0000', 'opacity' : '1' })

    });
```

Comment: OMG!! With <ul></ul> empty don't work, but if i put some code inside WORK!!!!! Thanks to everybody!

you can use my first code, but only if you have some code inside <ul></ul>

Comment: this is CHROME CONSOLE.GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js  index.html:9
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined carousel_content.js:3
(anonymous function) carousel_content.js:3
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/thaymus/Desktop/NUEVO%20VEKTORLAB/html/carousel/todos.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: works fine in Firefox, InternetExplorer, and Safari. Not working in Chrome and Opera.
You can see it here

[link](http://www.vektorlab.com/nuevo/index.html)

Comment: OK, online WORK. Not in Local

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#foo2").load("carousel/todos.html", function(){
          $(this).animate({ "opacity":"1" });
          $('#carouselselectitem1').css({ 'color' : '#FF0000', 'opacity' : '1' });
        });
    });
</script>
```

or may be this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#foo2").ready(function () {
        $(this) load("carousel/todos.html", function () {
          $(this).animate({"opacity": "1"});
          $('#carouselselectitem1').css({'color': '#FF0000', 'opacity': '1'});
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```